# How do I manipulate shadows in Three.js without editing the underlying mesh?

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl

I'm working on an app that should allow users to manipulate 3D objects in the scene and observe how their changes affect the ground shadow:

[image]

In this scene, the yellow cylinder casts a shadow on a white plane with the middle of the cylinder contained in the green cube. What I would like to happen is for the cube to remove the middle of the shadow, like so:

[image]

Obviosly, my first thought was to subtract the green cube volume from the yellow cylinder volume and after a bit of googling I found CSG.js. Unfortunately, CSG.js is too slow for the actual model that I'm going to use, which will going to have at least 15k vertices.

I started digging into the Three.js source and reading about shadow maps to understand how shadows are produced, but my shader-fu is not strong enough yet to fully grasp how I can tweak shadow rendering.

How can I achieve this "shadow subtraction" effect?

```
var camera, scene, renderer;

init();
animate();

function init() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
  camera.position.z = 500;
  camera.position.y = 100;
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);

  var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x909090);
  scene.add(ambient);

  var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1.0 );
  directionalLight.position.set( -300, 300, 0 );
  directionalLight.castShadow = true;
  directionalLight.shadow.camera.near    =   10;
  directionalLight.shadow.camera.far     =   2000;
  directionalLight.shadow.camera.right   =   350;
  directionalLight.shadow.camera.left    =  -350;
  directionalLight.shadow.camera.top     =   350;
  directionalLight.shadow.camera.bottom  =  -350;
  directionalLight.shadow.mapSize.width  = 1024;
  directionalLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;
  scene.add( directionalLight );

  //var lightHelper = new THREE.CameraHelper(directionalLight.shadow.camera);
  //scene.add(lightHelper);

  var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 50, 50, 400, 32 );
  var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} );
  var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  cylinder.castShadow = true;
  scene.add( cylinder );

  var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 110, 110, 110 );
  var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0x00ff00} );
  var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  cube.castShadow = true;
  scene.add( cube );

  var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 3000, 3000, 32 );
  var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0xffffff, side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
  var plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  plane.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0));
  plane.position.y = -200;
  plane.receiveShadow = true;
  scene.add( plane );

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
  renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.BasicShadowMap;
  document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

  window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
}

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );

  renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmvb92jp/)

**Update:**

What about a more complicated scene? Is it possible for the shadow from the red cylinder to be unaffected (you can see it being cut in half with `cube.customDepthMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ depthTest: false})`)?

[image]

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmvb92jp/3/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can subtract an object's shadow from the rest of scene by setting the object's `.customDepthMaterial` property  like so:

```
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
cube.castShadow = true;
cube.receiveShadow = false;

// The secret sauce
cube.customDepthMaterial =
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ depthTest: false});

scene.add( cube );
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmvb92jp/2/)

No shader-fu required.

**Why This Works**
When the shadow map is rendered, each object's depth material ( `.customDepthMaterial` or the default ) is [used to render the scene from the light's perspective](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/69079243426506ed86d0d0ea71b4fdda9dbb2f88/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLShadowMap.js#L256-L280). The depth material's resulting render represents the object's depth from the camera packed as RGBA. Since `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial` defaults to `{ color: 0xffffff, opacity: 1 }`, it will return the maximum depth which makes the object further than the shadow camera's `far`.

I disabled `depthTest` because in your desired result screenshot you clipped the area where the cube's given the cylinder wasn't there. Disabling `depthTest` means that parts of the cube which are blocked by the cylinder will still cut out the shadow, giving you your desired result.

**Documentation**
There unfortunately is no documentation on `.customDepthMaterial` yet but I did find [an official example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_animation_cloth) where it is used.

**Updated Answer:**
To allow an object's shadow to always show:

1. You can use the same trick as above just setting the material's `color` and `opacity` to `0`
2. Make sure it's added to the scene after the 'subtractive shadow' object. This way the additive shadow will win out even though they both have `depthTest` disabled.

[updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmvb92jp/4/)

If you have anything more complicated, it will be up to you to figure out a way to manage the order of the shadow rendering.

Tested in r77

Comment: The depth is packed into the `RGBA` channels. See `packing.glsl` in the library source.

Comment: @WestLangley Ah of course you're right! I'll update my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @LeJeuneRenard Very neat! What about a more complicated scene (see the question update)?